# PHP combine several arrays to one

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to combine several arrays into one, they are the result of a form post with an unknown number of elements, eg:

```
$ids = [53,54,55];
$names = ['fire','water','earth'];
$temps = [500,10,5];
```

What i want is to make a function that takes these arrays as an input and produces a single output, like

```
$elements = [['id'=>53,'name'=>'fire','temp'=>500] , ['id'=>54,'name'=>'water','temp'=>500] , ['id'=>55,'name'=>'earth','temp'=>500]]
```

I came up with the following solution:

```
function atg($array) {
  $result = array();
  for ($i=0;$i<count(reset($array));$i++) {
      $newAr = array();
      foreach($array as $index => $val) {
        $newAr[$index] = $array[$index][$i];
      }
      $result[]=$newAr;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

It can be called like

```
$elements = atg(['id' => $ids, 'name' => $names, 'temp' => $temps]);
```

And it produces the right output. To me it seems a bit overly complicated though, and I'm sure this is a common problem in PHP for form posts, combining seperate fields into a single array per item. What would be a better solution?

Comment: 3x `temp => 500` in your output, typo?

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through all of your 3 arrays at once with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). There you can just return the new array with a value of each of the 3 arrays, e.g.

```
$result = array_map(function($id, $name, $temp){
    return ["id" => $id, "name" => $name, "temp" => $temp];
}, $ids, $names, $temps);
```

Comment: Nice Answer :) Your output is changed temp value but OP has posted it as first index 500 to other array.

Comment: @RaviHirani Since OP's code doesn't implement that and he says that he gets the right output I assume it's just a typo in the question, but just to make sure I wrote a comment under OP's question.

Comment: Okay. I have highlighted it also. I also assume that it is Typo. Then I need to change my answer also :D

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:-

```
$ids = [53,54,55];
$names = ['fire','water','earth'];
$temps = [500,10,5];
$result = [];
foreach($ids as $k=>$id){
  $result[$k]['id'] = $id;
  $result[$k]['name'] =$names[$k];
  $result[$k]['temp'] = $temps[0];
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);
```

output:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 53
            [name] => fire
            [temp] => 500
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 54
            [name] => water
            [temp] => 500
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 55
            [name] => earth
            [temp] => 500
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with a destructive solution, array_shift could do the trick :

```
$elements = array();
while (!empty($ids)) {
  $elements[] = array(
    'id' => array_shift($ids),
    'name' => array_shift($names),
    'temp' => array_shift($temps),
   );
}
```

If you want to make a function, using the same arguments than your example, a solution could be

```
function atg($array) {
  $elements = array();

  while (!empty($array[0])) {
    $new_element = array();
    foreach ($array as $key_name => $array_to_shift) {
      $new_element[$key_name] = array_shit($array_to_shift);
    }
    $elements[] = $new_element;
  }
  return $elements;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$result[$ids]['name'] = $names[0];
$result[$ids]['temp'] = $temps[0]
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?